# Symfony Doctrine Migrations - Use transactions to wrap migrations

Tags: mysql, symfony, transactions, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

What I want to do : For every migrations executed with `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` to be wrapped in a proper transaction (START TRANSACTION / BEGIN / ROLLBACK / ...).

My config/doctrine_migrations.yml file contains the following options :

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
    enable_profiler: false
    # Run all migrations in a transaction.
    all_or_nothing: true
    # Adds an extra check in the generated migrations to ensure that is executed on the same database type.
    check_database_platform: true
    # Whether to wrap migrations in a single transaction.
    transactional: true
```

And in any case the isTransactional method from AbstractMigration returns true by default.

Am I missing something here ? Does "transactions" here have another meaning than what's I'm expecting ?

I'm running `symfony 6.3.7` with `doctine-migrations-bundle 3.2.4` on a `5.7.29 MySQL database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out the transactions are being set as expected **but** MySQL autocommits when executing a DDL statement (CREATE / ALTER TABLE / ...), so as soon as a DDL statement is run in a migration file, the transaction is commited and the transactionnal mode is turned off and there is no rollback to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

The `transactional` configuration value is apparently only used when *generating a new migration*, as [can be seen in the generator](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/e4e0855ea993d169c8adb50e19b014e64bbdda46/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Generator/Generator.php#L96-L103), when transactional is set to `false`, `AbstractMigration::isTransactional` will be overridden to return `false` instead.

**However** as user1717044 correctly notes, MySQL doesn't allow DDL statements (statements that change the schema) in transactions and will auto-commit those instead. This makes the feature largely useless for most people.

Comment: Indeed but the documentation of isTransactional() (which returns true in my situation since it's not overriden) says the following : `If this function returns true (default) the migration will be executed in one transaction, otherwise non-transactional state will be used to execute each of the migration SQLs. `

Given this, the execution of the migration _should_ be wrapped in a transaction ?

Comment: yes. It would be wrapped, but as you noted, MySQL will just autocommit anyway for DDLs (migrations could absolutely contain queries other than DDL statements, so it wouldn't generally be useless) but yeah, sorry.